# Spark "distribute by" explodes size of original data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm trying to figure out why my 15 GB table balloons to 182 GB when I run a simple query on it.

First I read the table into Spark from Redshift. When I tell Spark to do a simple count on the table, it works fine. However, when I try to create a table I get all kinds of YARN failures and ultimately some of my tasks have shuffle spill memory of 182 GB.

Here is the problematic query (I've changed some of the names):

```
CREATE TABLE output
  SELECT
    *
  FROM inputs
  DISTRIBUTE BY id
  SORT BY snapshot_date
```

What is going on? How could the shuffle spill exceed the total size of the input? I'm not doing a cartesian join, or anything like that. This is a super simple query.

I'm aware that Red Hat Linux (I use EMR on AWS) has virtual memory issues, since I came across that topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781354/container-killed-by-yarn-for-exceeding-memory-limits-10-4-gb-of-10-4-gb-physic/47831612#47831612), but I've added the recommended config `classification=yarn-site,properties=[yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false]`
 to my EMR properties and the issue persists.

Here is a screenshot from the Spark UI, if it helps:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if there is skew on column ID? try to run something similar to `select id,count(*) as cnt from inputs order by cnt desc limit 100`   to see if there are any outliers that might be causing huge spike of data on executor #66

Comment: How do you actually know that data in Redshift takes 15 GB?

Comment: @Pushkr My data is definitely skewed, but that doesn't explain why the shuffle spill would be 10x the size of the original input. @dytyniak Redshift tracks table MB size in a table called `svv_table_info`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html

Comment: Do you mind to share your spark-submit command ?

Comment: @PrateekPrateek I get these errors when running pyspark interactively. The command I use to start the shell is this: `pyspark --jars $JARS --driver-java-options -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///etc/alternatives/spark-conf/log4j.properties`

Comment: you have to provide proper memory. Try pyspark  --master yarn --driver-memory 10G --num-executors 5 --executor-memory 20G --executor-cores 5 . 

here master can be yarn or local  and adjust memory as per cluster