Spark Job failed in EMR with exit code 137
The spark job runs in emr with 7.2 version. It's failing with below error. Any advice or tips to debug?
Error
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1518 in stage 14.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1518.3 in stage 14.0 (TID 817317) (ip63.ec2.internal executor 3511): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3511 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_1726668126936_0001_01_004353 on host: ip-13-16.internal. Exit status: 137. Diagnostics: [2024-09-18 15:19:42.240]Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
[2024-09-18 15:19:42.241]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137.
[2024-09-18 15:19:42.241]Killed by external signal




You have this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194057/spark-on-emr-container-from-a-bad-node check the resolution
