# Tuning Spark for "Excessive" Parallelism on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I have a Spark job that reads in some TB of data and executes two window functions. This job runs just fine in smaller chunks, 50k shuffle partitions on 4TB, but when I increase the data input to 150k-200k shuffle partitions for 15TB nodes begin to fail.

This happens for two reasons:

- OOM on the Executors:
- Timeout when shuffling

**OOM on the Executors**

```
20/07/01 15:58:14 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 92 on ip-10-102-125-133.ec2.internal: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.  22.0 GB of 22 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.
```

I have already increased the size of the driver to account for the large shuffle:

- `spark.driver.memory = 16g`
- `spark.driver.maxResultSize = 8g`

The executors are R5.xlarge with the following conf:

- `spark.executor.cores = 4`
- `spark.executor.memory = 18971M`
- `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverheadFactor = 0.1875`

This is well below the max accordiing to AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html#emr-hadoop-task-config-r5

- `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 24576`

I understand I need to tweak `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverheadFactor` here to allow space for the massive overhead associated with this many partitions. Hopefully that will be the last change needed there.

**Shuffle Timeout**

```
20/07/01 15:59:39 ERROR TransportChannelHandler: Connection to ip-10-102-116-184.ec2.internal/10.102.116.184:7337 has been quiet for 600000 ms while there are outstanding requests. Assuming connection is dead; please adjust spark.network.timeout if this is wrong.
20/07/01 15:59:39 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 8 requests outstanding when connection from ip-10-102-116-184.ec2.internal/10.102.116.184:7337 is closed
20/07/01 15:59:39 ERROR OneForOneBlockFetcher: Failed while starting block fetches
```

I've adjusted this timeout as follows:

- `spark.network.timeout = 600`

I can further increase the `spark.network.timeout` in the conf to quiet this and wait longer. I would rather reduce the `Shuffle Read Blocked Time`, this is ranging from 1min to 30min. Is there a way to increase the communication rate between nodes?

I have tried adjusting the following settings, but can't seem to improve this speed:

- `spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight = 512m`
- `spark.shuffle.io.numConnectionsPerPeer = 5`
- `spark.shuffle.io.backLog = 128`

What do I need to tune to decrease the `Shuffle Read Blocked Time` on AWS EMR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OOM on executors , do this. It solved the issue for us.
from : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/

```
Even if all the Spark configuration properties are calculated and set correctly, virtual out-of-memory errors can still occur rarely as virtual memory is bumped up aggressively by the OS. To prevent these application failures, set the following flags in the YARN site settings.

Best practice 5: Always set the virtual and physical memory check flag to false.

"yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled":"false",
"yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled":"false"
```

Reason for that : ["Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 10.4 GB of 10.4 GB physical memory used" on an EMR cluster with 75GB of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781354/container-killed-by-yarn-for-exceeding-memory-limits-10-4-gb-of-10-4-gb-physic)

To resolve shuffle-timeout, try to increase your storage(EBS volumes).

Comment: Do you recommend multiple EBS volumes per node? If so, do I need to configure Spark to use all of the volumes?

Comment: Just increase the size , need not be multiple volumes.

Comment: Increasing the size did not work, but using multiple volumes did. Going to accept this solution because the yarn setting seemed to help!

Comment: hi Josh, what's the logic with adding multiple volumes?